# RSpec - expected equal?( Time Object ) to return true, got false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I'm trying (and failing!) the following code to compare two Time objects in RSpec:

```
describe '#current_shift_datetime' do
  subject { WipStack.current_shift_datetime }
  it "To be a Time object" do
    expect(subject).to be_kind_of(Time)
  end
  it "To return current shift datetime" do
    # Trying to figure out why they are not equal
    puts subject.in_time_zone.round
    puts 0.day.ago.midnight.in_time_zone.round

    # Problematic code here -->
    expect(subject.in_time_zone.round).to be_equal(0.day.ago.midnight.in_time_zone.round)
    # End of problematic code
  end
end
```

I have read a couple of things in the internet about rspec time comparisong, one of them explaining the problem with the milliseconds (therefore the round) and another page talking about `stub` but then i ended with `An error occurred in an after hook SystemStackError: stack level too deep`.

The ouput of the test is:

```
 1) WipStack#current_shift_datetime To return current shift datetime
    Failure/Error: expect(subject.in_time_zone.round).to be_equal(0.day.ago.midnight.in_time_zone.round)
    expected equal?(Mon, 17 Feb 2014 00:00:00 CST -06:00) to return true, got false
```

The puts output:

```
#current_shift_datetime
  To be a Time object
  2014-02-17 00:00:00 -0600
  2014-02-17 00:00:00 -0600
  To return current shift datetime (FAILED - 1)
```

**Update:**

Here is the `current_shift_datetime` method:

```
def WipStack.current_shift_datetime(scope = nil)
  shifts = WipStack.get_shifts(scope)
  current_shift = (Time.zone.now - 1.day).strftime("%m/%d/%Y")+" "+shifts.last
  current_time = Time.zone.now.strftime("%H:%M")
  shifts.each do |shift|
    if current_time > shift
      current_shift =  Time.zone.now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")+" "+shift
    end
  end
  Time.zone.parse(current_shift)
end
```

Comment: Lets have a look at the `current_shift_datetime` method

Comment: Thanks @CharlesJHardy here is the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than compare the time zones directly (and get bogged down in subtle differences), you could try comparing the string representations to each other, since that's what you're checking with in the console anyhow.

Depending on how you use this timezone in your app, this should be sufficient to say they are essentially the same time.

```
expect(subject.in_time_zone.round.to_s).to eq(0.day.ago.midnight.in_time_zone.round.to_s)
```

You could probably drop the `.round` if you wanted to as well.

**EDIT**

Try changing your code so there is no difference between what is printed and what is compared:

```
it "To return current shift datetime" do
  a = subject.in_time_zone.round.to_s
  b = 0.day.ago.midnight.in_time_zone.round.to_s

  puts a
  puts b

  expect(a).to eq(b)
end
```

Comment: Now i'm confused as i really thought this would fix it but for a reason i do not understand this gives me the same error...`1) WipStack#previous_shift_datetime To return last shift datetime
     Failure/Error: expect(subject.to_s).to be_equal(1.day.ago.midnight.to_s)
       expected equal?("2014-02-16 00:00:00 -0600") to return true, got false`

Comment: according to puts it's the same string `To be a Time object
2014-02-16 00:00:00 -0600
2014-02-16 00:00:00 -0600`

Comment: Great, glad to help. Feel free to mark it as correct.

Comment: I will give you a up, but using the `equal` fails the test

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it thanks to `tyler!` It seems that be_equal was actually trying to see if both objects were the same (a comment appear on the test failing when comparing the strings), changing be_equal to eq made the test pass!

```
it "To return current shift datetime" do
  #pending
  puts subject.in_time_zone.round.to_s
  puts 0.day.ago.midnight.in_time_zone.round.to_s
  expect(subject.in_time_zone.round.to_s).to eq(0.day.ago.midnight.in_time_zone.round.to_s)
end
```

Comment: please do accept the answer instead of duplicating it